# Confusion in building a Svm Training Set

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, svm

I am currently testing the training phase of my Binary SVM Java implementation.
I have tested it for small data shown below, but I need to apply my svm to a known dataset like spam/not spam, images, etc.

1. My SVM is capable of reading numeric values so I need to test it with some real data also.
2. Later I want to move on to images.

To find a real data set, I searched through different repos, but all I could find was numerical values + characters, text, etc.

And I found a [spam Archive](http://untroubled.org/spam/).

1. But how do I proceed with that?
2. I think I need to convert the text into numerical data using tfidf and then apply my SVM.
3. But how do I indicate them as 1/-1 class.

Normally the input would be of this format right?

```
0 0 1
3 4 1
5 9 1
12 1 1 
8 7  1
9 8 -1
6 12 -1
10 8 -1
8 5 -1
14 8 -1
```

How do I bring the spam archive data into the above format?

Comment: The LIBSVM group has a bunch of test data available if you're looking for pre-cooked test data.

Comment: Thank you for the response tmyklebu: can u share the link with me for those dataset.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the features selections. The input is of course the pairs of documents and labels. But the feature extraction is included in the training process. The most straightforward way is the binary representation, in which we check whether a particular word occurs in some particular documents. It is also referred to term frequency: the ith components in the feature vector is the time word wi occurs in one document. Here the vector is a established dictionary that included all the words in the training documents. You may also consider the inverse document frequency: number of times that wi occurs in all documents divided by the total number of documents.
FYI, one research paper about SVM on spam:
http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps290c/Spring12/lect/14/00788645-SVMspam.pdf

Comment: one feature vector per message.If i convert all messages to TFIDF i will be getting numeric values..but i am confused ,how to put the label.1 for spam and -1 for not spam. is that archicev a combination of spam not spam text data?

Comment: @Sree, you may select those words that appear most frequently in your training set, say, 1000 document frequency terms. And don't use those words if they occurs less than , say, 20 times. And usually the training set is ~10^5 (documents, or emails).

Comment: so after doining tfidf for spam archieve i should label all the data as 1 and for not spam label as -1 then snd to svm...